# How mobile tower functions?

Tags: multiplexer, cellphone, telecommunications

How mobile tower handle so many users calls does they use multiplexers ? Or which device they use?

Comment: You should do some basic research on google. There is lots of information about.

Comment: This is not the best site to start a discussion, as discussions are against the guidelines http://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask http://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic

Comment: ok, can you suggest some websites ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They don't so much *use* a multiplexer, as the entire radio access system is designed to *be* a multiplexer. The ability to serve multiple users at the same time is baked-in to the specification of the air interface

1G, AMPS and TACS, use different frequencies for different channels

2G, GSM etc, 8 callers time-share a single carrier, and there are multiple carriers

3G and 4G, it all gets too complicated for one sentence, but multiple users share multiple frequencies, time slots *and* spreading codes